# How exactly does conv1d filter work when operating on a sequence of characters?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq, torch

I understand convolution filters when applied to an image (e.g. an 224x224 image with 3 in-channels transformed by 56 total filters of 5x5 conv to a 224x224 image with 56 out-channels). The key is that there are 56 different filters each with 5x5x3 weights that end up producing output image 224x224, 56 (term after comma is output channels).

But I can't seem to understand how `conv1d` filter works in seq2seq models on a sequence of characters. One of the models i was looking at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05884.pdf has a "*post-net layer is comprised of 512 filters with shape 5×1"* that operates on a spectrogram frame 80-d (means 80 different float values in the frame), and the result of filter is a 512-d frame.

- I don't understand what `in_channels, out_channels` mean in pytorch conv1d definition as in images I can easily understand what in-channels/out-channels mean, but for sequence of 80-float values frames I'm at loss. What do they mean in the context of seq2seq model like this above?
- How do 512, 5x1 filters on 80 float values produce 512 float values?**
- Wouldn't a 5x1 filter when operating on 80 float values just produce 80 float values (by just taking 5 consecutive values at a time of those 80)? How many weights total these 512 filters have?**

The layer when printed in pytorch shows up as:

```
(conv): Conv1d(80, 512, kernel_size=(5,), stride=(1,), padding=(2,))
```

and the parametes in this layer show up as:

```
postnet.convolutions.0.0.conv.weight : 512x80x5 = 204800
```

- Shouldn't the weights in this layer instead be 512*5*1 as it only has 512 filters each of which is 5x1?

Answer (score 1):

1D convolution can be best imagined as applying a sliding window of projections over a sequence of vectors. *Kernel size* is the window width, *stride* is the size of the step the window makes.

In your example, you have a sequence of vectors of dimension 80 – input channels, and you want to get a sequence of vectors of dimension 512 – output channels. You apply a sliding window of width 5, i.e. for every window of 80×5 numbers, you need to make a projection into 512 dimensions. This is where  512×80×5 comes from.

You can imagine it as concatenating the 5 vectors in the sliding window into a one long vector of 80×5=400 dimensions. Then you take this 400-dimensional vector and multiply it with a matrix of 400×512 trainable paramters to get a vector of 512 dimensions.